# jQuery scrollable question

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollable

I am wondering how I can fade out a div box before scrollable starts and fade it in after the animation stops? Because for me it looks like I start scrollable and then it runs in background and looks for events.

Is there a function like `onBeforeStart()` or similar?

Greets
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#element').fadeOut('slow', function(){
//start scrollable and fadein here
})
```

by doing this, Scrollable starts only after fadeout is complete.

**UPDATE**

Using scrollable from jQuery tools, you can use the events `onBeforeSeek` and `onSeek` to fire an action before scroller starts or after it completes. You can read more about the events in the documentation at http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html.

To run a function after scrolling has completed, you do something like this

```
$("#element").scrollable({
    onSeek: function(event, i) {
         //Whatever goes here         
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. And how can I determine if the scrollable animation has finished?

Comment: jQuery doesn't come with a scrollable function. What plugin are you using for that.